# Customize Create folder button in UIViewController in edit mode

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have an application and I want to customize the create folder button when it is on edit mode.

I used following code to do that:

```
UIBarButtonItem * addButton;
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(createFolder)];
[addButton setTitleTextAttributes:dictionaryOfTitleTextAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"List/newfolder-normal.png"].CGImage scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 14, 4, 14)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"List/newfolder-touched.png"].CGImage scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4,14,4,14)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But I couldn't remove the plus sign in create new folder button and the app seemed like this

[image]

How can I remove the plus sign?

Comment: implement with provided code answer and let me Know this is working or not?

Comment: you have to reply about answer is useful or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As par you implement code you simply define you `UIBarButtonItem` using `initWithTitle` like Bellow

```
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(createFolder:)];
```

Example code:-

```
UIBarButtonItem * addButton;
    addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(createFolder:)];
    //[addButton setTitleTextAttributes:di forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redHeart.png"].CGImage scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 14, 4, 14)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [addButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueheart.png"].CGImage scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4,14,4,14)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**OUTPUT IS**

[image]

i suggest you to use `UIButton` and set as a `CustomView` of `UIbarButtonItem` for doing this task:-

```
UIImage* yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newfolder-normal.png.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImage.size.width, yourImage.size.height);
someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
someButton.tag=1;
[someButton setBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createFolder:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

addButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarbuttonITem=addButton;
[someButton release];


-(void)createFolder:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

  //If checked, uncheck and visa versa
  [selectedButton setSelected:![selectedButton isSelected]];

  if([selectedButton isSelected])
  {
      UIImage* yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"List/newfolder-touched.png"];    
    [selectedButton setBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
  else
  {
    UIImage* yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"List/newfolder-normal.png"];    
    [selectedButton setBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}
```